Cannot enable A2DP Profile Kubuntu 24.04
I have an Asus Vivobook that I recently installed bluetooth drivers for and I can get my wireless headphones to connect, but only with HSP/HFP profiles.  I'd like to enable A2DP for high-quality audio.  I know the headphones I am using support this, because they have high-quality sound on all other devices.  I know that A2DP is possible on my laptop because I can find this when using systemctl status | grep a2dp:
           │ │ └─1044 /usr/bin/bluealsa -S -p a2dp-source -p a2dp-sink
                 │ │ └─5331 grep --color=auto -i a2dp

so the profile does exist on this laptop.  But when I check for profile options on this device in any place I can think to, only the HSP/HFP profiles and codecs are shown.  I've tried to do some of my own research but so far I've just managed to crash PipeWire and bring  it back, not actually get A2DP working.  I've found a few discussions/articles on similar topics, but none that address my issue of A2DP not presenting at all.
